# Microsoft Teams + Azure Bot: Intermittent Error 403 "The bot is not part of the conversation roster"

Tags: azure, botframework, bots, microsoft-teams

I'm debugging the issue with my microsoft bot, registered in Azure, and MS Teams. It is intermittent issue. The thing is that sometimes I'm getting this error message when my bot is trying to notify MS Teams:

```
{
    "error":{
        "code":"BotNotInConversationRoster",
        "message":"The bot is not part of the conversation roster."
    }
}
```

No luck with googling it or searching it in microsoft docs. Also, no errors or warnings in Azure bot activity log.

In Azure in Home -> My Bot -> Channels -> MS Teams -> Warnings, I see this, but it doesn't really help:

```
7/22/2019, 3:41:37 PM   The bot is not part of the conversation roster.
7/22/2019, 11:24:45 AM  The bot is not part of the conversation roster.
7/19/2019, 1:04:26 PM   The bot is not part of the conversation roster.
7/19/2019, 12:08:34 PM  The bot is not part of the conversation roster.
7/19/2019, 12:04:50 PM  The bot is not part of the conversation roster.
7/19/2019, 11:37:56 AM  The bot is not part of the conversation roster.
7/19/2019, 11:23:21 AM  The bot is not part of the conversation roster.
7/19/2019, 11:15:17 AM  The bot is not part of the conversation roster.
7/16/2019, 12:21:42 PM  Unknown
```

Has anybody encountered this issue? What can it be? How can I fix it?

Any help is really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is App still installed in these teams? Do you have repro for this?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT yes, app is still installed, but the think is it is intermittent issue, so you have to be lucky to reproduce it. Just tried it, not able to reproduce it right now.

Comment: It seems to take hours sometimes for bot apps added to a Team to actually start working.  Everything in Teams that requires replicating around takes forever, there seems to be caches all up and down the stack.

Comment: I got the same error but when trying to update an existing message by using their REST API [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/update-and-delete-bot-messages?tabs=rest)